# Combine strings contained in variables delimited by a new line

Tags: bash, awk, delimiter

I have three variables in Bash, all of them containing strings delimited by a new line, e.g.:

Variable A:

```
one
two
three
```

Variable B:

```
Mon
Tue
Wed
```

Variable C:

```
10
11
12
```

The three variables always hold the exact same number of elements delimited by a new line.

My goal is to take a line (starting from the first one) from variable A, add some text in between, then take a line from variable B, add some text in between again, and finally, take a line from variable C and add some text at the end. Then, i want to append the result of this to a final variable, let's say $final, that after the loop is over (i.e., we have walked through all the lines), should look like this:

`one - Mon [10]; two - Tue [11]; three - Wed [12]`

Is awk capable of that or i should use other tools?

Comment: Doesn't handle the whitespace the way you want, but: `paste -d -[] <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") <(echo "$C") | sed 's/$/];/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
# assign the variables
variableA="one
two
three"

variableB="Mon
Tue
Wed"

variableC="10
11
12"

# transform the variables to arrays
readarray -t aryA <<< "$variableA"
readarray -t aryB <<< "$variableB"
readarray -t aryC <<< "$variableC"

# construct the variable $final
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    final+="${aryA[$i]} - ${aryB[$i]} [${aryC[$i]}]; "
done

# remove trailing semicolon and whitespace
final="${final%;*}"

echo "$final"
```

Output:

```
one - Mon [10]; two - Tue [11]; three - Wed [12]
```

**[Explanation]**

- `readarray` (or `mapfile`) reads standard input line by line 
  and puts each line in an array element.
- That is, if `variableA` which contains the three lines is fed to `readarray`,
  then the array `aryA` is created containing `aryA[0]=one`,
  `aryA[1]=two`, and so on.
- Then the variable `final` is created by appending the elements of the arrays.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This time I came first? :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I would go with:

```
paste <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") <(echo "$C") \
| awk '{printf "%s - %s [%s]; ", $1, $2, $3}'
```